# Can copy-constructor with delete qualifier be private?

Tags: c++, delete-operator

All examples I found with the usage of 'delete' keyword were done on public functions:

```
class X
{
public:
   X(const X&) = delete;
};
```

Why they don't just use default private ones?

```
class X
{
X(const X&) = delete;
};
```